# Different dashboards based on same analyse run

Tags: sonarqube

```
Sonar-Qube: V.5.1.1
C#-Plugin: V.4.0
ReSharper-Plugin: V.2.0
```

Due to the long analyse runs I would like to have the following:
Let's assume I analyse my source with the rules A, B, C and D. Now I would like to have a dashboard based on the issues found with rule A and B and another dashboard based on the issues found with rules C and D and the third one basing on all rules. **But I don't want to have an analyse run for each of those combinations!** Curently an analyse run takes 4 hours!

Answer (score 0):

What you're after isn't possible.

===Edit===
Based on our comment conversation, I'd advise putting all rules in the same profile and setting the severity of "next year's" rules to Info. The teams can easily use the issues page to choose which sets of issues to see at one time.

When it's time to make rule set II official, you can simply upgrade the severities of the relevant rules.

Comment: Even not in enterprise edition? That would be a real cool feature saving a lot of time for analysing.

Comment: Okay, to be clear: did you want rule A applied to all of the code, or just a subset?

Comment: Sorry for the delay ... I try to be more precisely: I want to make one analyse run and after that I would like to e.g. 2 different dashboards of the same analysed sources, each of them with a different subset of rules.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I don't really understand why you'd want it anyway. Unless you're after graphing different types of issues over time? In that case, you'd have to write a plugin to create custom metrics based on issue counts.

Comment: Right now an analyse run of one of our soultions takes 4 hours. In our company we have 200+ solutions to scan. We want to run a migration strategy for all those solutions. Let's say ruleset No. 1 is mandatory and contains 3 rules (A, B and C). We annonce the next ruleset No. 2 containing 5 rules (A, B, C, D and E) to be mandatory next year. Now every dev team should be able to have a dashboard based on ruleset No. 1 and another based on ruleset No. 2. I know that I could achieve that by having an analyse run for each ruleset. But to save execution time I want to have only one run.